# Git merging and commit issue

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

I have 2 branches - master and develop
While I am on the develop branch, I have commit and pushed a change (Added in a file) and it is successful.

However, when I type `git checkout master`, followed by `git merge develop`... Instead of getting the output messages like (I am copying this message from a previous merge that I did), and did a `git push`:

```
Updating 325ac4a..51ffb06
Fast-forward
Test_Folder/Images/Img_01.jpg | Bin 0 -> 4224 bytes
2 files changed, 1 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 Test_Folder/Images/Img_01.jpg
```

I was asked to add in a commit message in the Terminal itself... 
This is very different from all the previous merging that I have did and it is the first time I have seen it. Though I managed to get pass the `commit` followed by a `git push`, am I doing it wrong somehow?

Even so, should the above 'issue' seems correct, is there any way that I can commit the message without going thru the terminal style?
(By the way, I tried to do using `git gui` but apparently I am seeing no files or whatsoever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a true merge this time round and fast-forward merges previously.

Take a peek at [git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for the difference between the two.

PS: It is completely normal to do a true merge. However many collaborated environments tend to disallow them since these are the merges which can actually result in conflicts. A fast-forward merge will never conflict. But again, both are very normal.

Edit: Here's the situation in which a particular kind of merge gets done:

1) **Fast-forward merge**: This is performed when your `master` is direct ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge in it.

```
--*--*--*(master, HEAD)--*--*--*(dev)
```

In this case, performing the merge means just moving the `master` reference to `dev`. The end result would look like:

```
--*--*--*--*--*(master, dev, HEAD)
```

2) **True merge**: This happens when `master` is not a direct ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge.

```
--*--*--*--*(master, HEAD)
         \
           --*--*--*(dev)
```

In this case, `master` has moved forward from the point on which the `dev` branch was created. As such, during merging, we will have to include the changes of that new commit(s) on `master` too. So git will try to create an entirely new commit which inherits from both branches and moves `master` to it.

```
-*--*--*--*---------*(master, HEAD)
        \          /
          --*--*--*(dev)
```

Compare this to ff merge and you will see why they are so named. `HEAD` denotes the current branch.

I hope I have explained this a bit clearer this time.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Just like to know how or when would I know that Git is going to perform a true merge or a fast forward merge? It seems like a random Git gag on me....

Comment: @user3212246 Whenever your develop branch and master branch evolve parallely, that will always need a true merge, and thus will always create a merge commit.

Comment: Thanks guys.. Probably I am figuring out how in the first place did my `master` is not the head of it... Now seems to me that in almost all of my merging is of a fast-forward merge...